# Martingale convergence $\Rightarrow$ non uniformly integrable?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

$\sup_{n} E[|X_{n}|\mathbb{1}_{[X_{n}|>c}]\rightarrow0$ as $c \rightarrow \infty$, being the definition of uniform integrability, should not occur if the martingale converges? Why is that?

Further, one apparently can argue that $E[X_{n}]=c \not=0 \Rightarrow$ non-uniformly integrable, though I do not see also how this should work (the indicator function within the expectation I thought would have allowed $E[X_{n}]=c$ to not negate u.i.)

Comment: Which notion of martingale convergence are you referring to? Almost surely or $L^1$? Either way, it is certainly possible that the martingale converge and be uniformly integrable : in fact  if  the convergence is in $L^1$ then uniform integrability can be shown easily.

Comment: a.s. -- perhaps though, the argument I am trying to decipher works because it is also true that $E[X_{n}] =$const

Comment: that is, there is martingale convergence and the expectation at each n is a constant.

Comment: If $X_n$ is a martingale, then from the tower property it is clear that $E[X_n]  = E[X_0]$ is a constant. I don't see what you are trying to prove. Are you trying to prove that if a martingale  converges a.s. then it is not uniformly integrable?

Comment: either that 1. Martingale converges then not u.i., 2. constant expectation implies not u.i., or 3. martingale converges AND expectation constant implies not u.i.  -- Unfortunately the proof I am reading was not really clear about the predicate used but stated that the expectation was constant for all $n$ and that the martingale converges, therefore "clearly" it is not u.i.

Comment: I guess the problem for me is that I am not seeing how that all connects with the definition of u.i. (shouldnt $\sup_{n} E[|X_{n}|\mathbb{1}_{[X_{n}|>c}]\rightarrow0$ still be the case?)

Comment: Oh ok, I think that equivalence was not immediately apparent to me. Thanks!

Comment: Definitely the one where you explain the equivalence and the comment you made prior to that

Comment: I am done, thanks for the conversation(+1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COMMENT 1 : See, a uniformly integrable martingale which converges almost surely, converges in $L^1$ as well. As a consequence, whatever random variable $X_n$ converges a.s. to, must have the same expectation as $X_0$. Now, if it is clear from the construction of the $X_n$ that you are looking at, that the limit does not have the same expectation as $X_0$ (or any of the $X_i$) then "clearly" the martingale is not UI, where "clearly" is to the author(and to you now)!

COMMENT 2 : The definition of UI is not used in the "clearly" part, it seems. Instead the following fact is used : given a sequence of (integrable) random variables $X_n$ and a random variable $Y$, the fact that $X_n  \to Y$ in probability and $X_n$ is UI, is equivalent to $X_n \to Y$ in $L^1$. In your context, I want you to find the $Y$ which the $X_n$ goes to a.s. and hence in probability. Maybe by looking at the expectations you can see that $X_n \to Y$ in $L^1$ is not possible, and therefore $X_n$ cannot be UI.

Comment: Also, for reference, your answer pointed me to the generalization of my problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for the reference!